# Alexa Tester cant invoke the skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, flask-ask, amazon-echo-show

I'm developing an Alexa Custom Skill. I want to have Beta Testing for the same. I added few emails to the Skill Beta Testing facility by Amazon. After accepting the invitation, it seems the Testers can't invoke the skill(They have enabled the skill). Neither from the Amazon Alexa App nor from the Echo Show Device(which is registered to the tester). But if tested on Test Simulator, it works. I want to have the skill work on Echo devices with the tester accounts. Help regarding the same.

Answer (score 2):

We also faced similar problems.

Our resolution - It seems that if the geographic area of the tester is same as of the skill it should work.